# Scala Map object to be split on the basis of a value property

Tags: scala

I have a map in my scala code, that has a string as a key and a userdefined object as the value. I want to split this map to three different map objects based on a property of the value.

Is this possible? Can someone share a way to do this? I have been trying to search but no example could be found. I am a novice at scala and appreciate any help...

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you had a map of person's and you wanted to divide that into three maps based on the age of a person.

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val map = Map(
  "p1" -> Person("person_1", 15),
  "p2" -> Person("person_2", 30),
  "p3" -> Person("person_3", 40),
  "p4" -> Person("person_4", 55),
  "p5" -> Person("person_5", 65)
)
// map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Person] = Map(p4 -> Person(person_4,55), p5 -> Person(person_5,65), p3 -> Person(person_3,40), p2 -> Person(person_2,30), p1 -> Person(person_1,15))


val dividedMaps = map.groupBy({ case (key, person) =>
  if (person.age < 20 ) "teenager"
  else if (person.age < 50) "adult"
  else "old"
})
// dividedMaps: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Person]] = Map(old -> Map(p4 -> Person(person_4,55), p5 -> Person(person_5,65)), teenager -> Map(p1 -> Person(person_1,15)), adult -> Map(p3 -> Person(person_3,40), p2 -> Person(person_2,30)))
```